# Email Template ChatterPhoto image not shown in gmail

Tags: apex, visualforce, email, chatter, profile

I have an email template defined in salesforce which uses custom components.
Eveything works fine. But i am also showing chatter image of the lead owner i.e user.

```
<img src="{!leadOwner.FullPhotoUrl}"  width="58" height="58" align="middle" />
```

which generates

```
<img align="middle" alt="alex" height="58" src="https://c.cs5.content.force.com/profilephoto/729O00000004Gjz/F" width="58">
```

Problem is the Gmail do not show this image.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/zOByJ58s8uRZn-AfYwBUlicwnihwa9s39sV…=s0-d-e1-ft#https://c.cs5.content.force.com/profilephoto/729O00000004Gju/F

[Images not showing up in Email sent using email template](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21706/images-not-showing-up-in-email-sent-using-email-template)
Have seen this link but this works only with documents can we do it for chatter profile image too.

Also, i would like to know if there is a way to implement view online option for my email so that regardless of what clients browser/mail provider supports, i can gracefuly show my content.

Comment: I don't think you can access chatter photo outside salesforce with a direct url.. https://c.cs5.content.force.com/profilephoto/729O00000004Gjz/F will work only within salesforce :-(

Comment: Ok this mean i am able to view the image only because i am logged in.

Comment: If you are willing to go to a lot of trouble, you can replicate the Blob data from the `FullPhotoUrl` (via a trigger on User) as an "Externally Available Image" document and save the document's public URL in a new field on User called e.g. `ExternallyAvailableFullPhotoUrl__c` that you can reference in your email templates.

Comment: Thanks Keith this looks promising. How about view online option. do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you use either Chatter in Apex or the Chatter REST API, you can retrieve image URLs that can be used in email messages. They're temporary and expire after 30 days.

Chatter in Apex:

[ConnectApi.ChatterUsers.getPhoto(String communityId, String userId)](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterUsers_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterUsers_getPhoto) returns a [ConnectApi.Photo](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_connectapi_output_photo.htm) object that contains fullEmailPhotoUrl and standardEmail​PhotoUrl properties.

Chatter REST API:

[GET /chatter/users/*userId*](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/chatterapi/Content/connect_resources_users_UserProfileInformation.htm) returns a [Photo representation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/chatterapi/Content/connect_responses_pictures.htm) that also contains the fullEmailPhotoUrl and standardEmail​PhotoUrl properties.