# Add logo image to html email template

Tags: community, email-template, html, images, letterhead

I have a small (hopefully) issue that I'm not able to find a solution to.I've added a logo to Documents in SF Classic, to use in an html template for when users need to create and send emails from Salesforce. My problem is the logo image shows as broken everytime I send an email. I've added the image to the Shared Documents folder, copied the long url and pasted it into my html. First picture is how it looks like sent to a gmail account, second is how it looks like sent to an outlook account. Everything else works besides this. Help much appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this behavior with the image uploaded on document object.The possible reason for this behavior is that Salesforce is unable to find the image in the Salesforce documents as it is being added through the browser/upload option.

Recommend you to use a URL like https://cti712-dev-ed--c.ap4.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?oid=00D6F000002Rhob&id=0156F00000Lkkbe instead of the long URL in your HTML Email Template which is basically

> https://{SALESFORCE-INSTANCE}.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?oid={ORG-ID}&id={DOC-ID}
> [image]

Also see [reference](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21706/images-not-showing-up-in-email-sent-using-email-template)

Comment: hi. did you use the inspect url that shows after clicking view to see the image in the documents tab and inspecting the image instead of using the SF url TO the image? it's working like that and it's awesome. thank you very much but now I'm just wondering, because I don't have access to production on the project I'm working on, how will I make it work on there also. I'll probably have to have them go through these steps so we can make it functional on there too.