# Images attached using Email Template Builder not displaying in Outlook

Tags: email-template, images

This question might have been asked a lot, went through a few posts they didn't help.

I am trying to attach images to the email template using email template builder in Salesforce. I was able to do that successfully and I do see that image in the template. When testing out the template by sending a test email I do see the text of the template in outlook but not the image. This is what I see in Outlook where the image is supposed to render
[image]

I have tried a few steps as mentioned on some of the posts here.

I uploaded it to Files as Documents is not available in lightning. After uploading it to files then I created a public link to make it externally available. Here is the post which I referred for this [Images not showing up in Email sent using email template](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21706/images-not-showing-up-in-email-sent-using-email-template)

I tried putting it as a link using the img src tag - that didn't work.

I tried allow images after the email is received in outlook.

None of the above worked.

Please advise!

Comment: it'd be great to link to the few posts you went through that didn't help as well. Is this only occurring in outlook or have you reproduced this in other email clients?

Comment: Sorry, I went through quite a few posts, I just lost them after looking around for long.  I am not worried about other email clients as Outlook is what my company use.

Comment: Here is one I went through, instead of documents I uploaded it to Files as Documents is not available in lightning. After uploading it to files then I created 
a public link  -https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21706/images-not-showing-up-in-email-sent-using-email-template this

Comment: I'd [edit] that link into your question. The reason I ask about other email clients is to pinpoint the issue further: whether it's an outlook-specific issue, an email template issue, etc.

Comment: Added the link to the post. I just forwarded the email I received on company email to gmail. It is not rendering there as well. It just gives me the title of the image.

Comment: I just tried sharing the uploaded file with a public group, for some reason I am not able to see the public groups of the org when sharing. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: Does anyone have had issues like this before, please help out. Also want to confirm the issue is not Outlook specific, does not work on Gmail as well.

Comment: There's many variables at play here - I'd start with going through the [help doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000324370&type=1) specific to this scenario.

Comment: Okay Thanks @KrisGoncalves

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to reply back to this thread as I was struggling with this as well. Hope it finds you well.

So when you make the image public by having the link, that link itself is not to the picture, but to an "app" that displays a picture with a download button in header. So if you want to actually link the picture to your email template builder, you need to follow the link and go to the "app", then right click the image and copy image address. Paste that new link to the builder for image and voilà!